# Trouble configuring secure proxy in wso2esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to use wso2esb similar to the sample #200 which exposes a secure web service and removes the security headers before invoking an unsecured service on another host/port.  I was able to do this and even integrate both a validator and password callback handler, but I have not been able to either copy the installation where I have this working to another system or configure another system to work in the same way.

I have tried to configure this proxy starting with a clean installation of 3.0.1, 4.0.3 and most recently 4.5.0 all with similar results, namely security errors either loading the credentials or most recently "recovering the key".

We have our own CA certificate and issue certs signed with that cert to customers who then use their private keys to encrypt and sign the SOAP.  I am using the following security policy file and have tried it both with and without the callback handlers.

I have tried to reference this policy file both by pasting it into the admin GUI after enabling security on this proxy service.

I have tried with version 3.0, which I have working on one server, also with 4.0.3 and most recently with 4.5.0 adjusting the location of the server.jks keystore as needed based on changes to the layout of wso2esb with the different versions.

I would very much appreciate help in configuring a secured proxy service with a sequence of steps that might allow me to get this working on multiple systems.

Thanks in advance !!

My proxy service is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="secureService"
statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="https,http">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <header action="remove" name="wsse:Security" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
    </inSequence>
    <endpoint>
        <address statistics="disable" trace="disable" uri="http://192.168.55.201:8083/NotSecureEJB/RemoteService">
            <timeout>
                <duration>0</duration>
                <action>discard</action>
            </timeout>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
            </markForSuspension>
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
</target>
<policy key="sec_policy"/>
<enableSec/>
```

Security Policy referenced from local-entries via:

```
<loccalEntry key="sec_policy" src="file:repository/resources/security/sec_policy.xml"/>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SigEncr" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
  <sp:AsymmetricBinding  xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
  <sp:InitiatorToken>
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
    </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:X509Token>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:InitiatorToken>
  <sp:RecipientToken>
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
    </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:X509Token>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:RecipientToken>
  <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
  <sp:Layout>
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:Strict/>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:Layout>
  <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
</wsp:Policy>
  </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
  <sp:SymetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:Basic128/>
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
  </sp:SymetricBinding>
  <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
  <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
  <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
</wsp:Policy>
  </sp:Wss10>
  <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Timestamp/>
<sp:Body/>
  </sp:SignedParts>
  <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
  </sp:EncryptedParts>
  <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy"> 
<ramp:user>server</ramp:user>
<ramp:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</ramp:encryptionUser>
<ramp:passwordCallbackClass>com.testing.PWCallback</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
<ramp:policyValidatorCbClass>com.testing.CustomPolicyValidator</ramp:policyValidatorCbClass>
<ramp:encryptionSymAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc</ramp:encryptionSymAlgorithm>
<ramp:encryptionKeyTransportAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5</ramp:encryptionKeyTransportAlgorithm>
<ramp:signatureCrypto>
  <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">
    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>
    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">resources/security/server.jks</ramp:property>
    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">changeme</ramp:property>
  </ramp:crypto>
</ramp:signatureCrypto>
<ramp:encryptionCypto>
  <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">
    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>
    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">resources/security/server.jks</ramp:property>
    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">changeme</ramp:property>
  </ramp:crypto>
</ramp:encryptionCypto>
  </ramp:RampartConfig>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```